# Writing VB code for Oscilloscope as C# code

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I usually work in VB with my oscilloscope (the oscilloscope has it's own OS). Now I am trying to make a C# executable which does the same thing as my VB code and run it on the oscilloscope.

I am trying to write the following VB code to C#:

```
Set app = CreateObject("LeCroy.XStreamDSO")
wave = app.Acquisition.C1.Out.Result.DataArray 
msgbox(wave(1))
```

What it does is basically connect to my oscilloscope software and output the first element of the waveform array.

This is what I have tried so far in C#: 
I made a form in VS2015 and made the target .NET 4.0 since my oscilloscope is running WindowsXP and it only has .NET 4.0 installed.

```
System.Type objType = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("LeCroy.XStreamDSO");
dynamic comObject = System.Activator.CreateInstance(objType);
var wave = comObject.Acquisition.C1.Out.Result.DataArray;
MessageBox.Show(wave(1));
```

Basically i put this code inside a button on my form. When I run this on the oscilloscope as an executable I get the error: "Unhandled exception has occurred in your application." "Cannot invoke non-delegate type".

Can anyone help me with what I am doing wrong? Would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Not sure if this is useful or not, but Microsoft has a guide on [Exposing COM Components to the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6tx9dw3(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Having said that... LeCroy may have a .NET driver for your Oscilloscope already.  I'm not sure if [this IVI driver](http://sine.ni.com/apps/utf8/niid_web_display.download_page?p_id_guid=E3B19B3E9511659CE034080020E74861) is for your model, though.

Comment: Instead of `wave(1)` try `wave[1]`.  C# uses square brackets for array access.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Good catch, I missed that.

Comment: Thanks for the very fast replies. I changed `wave(1)` to `wave[1]` (I don't know how I didn't catch this in the first place..). I ran the executable on the oscilloscope and now I get this error: 
"_The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(string)_' has some invalid arguments.". Is there a way to verify that the VB equivalent for CreateObject is working properly?

@Powerlord: Unfortunately it is not supported by my device. I am using a LeCroy 44Xi

Comment: You may need to use `wave[1].ToString()`.  I'm guessing that the wave array is not an array of strings.  Also double check the `Show` method and make sure you are passing all the necessary parameters.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Hey man that was it! It returns the first array point properly in the messagebox. I can start working off of this. Thanks a lot. How do I mark your comment as the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Since its .net4, you can use `dynamic` so :

```
Type myOscApp= Type.GetTypeFromProgID("LeCroy.XStreamDSO");
dynamic AppInstance= Activator.CreateInstance(myOscApp);
AppInstance.Visible = true;
```